# Reading data from csv file on the web using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a large csv file on the web "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_8*************/view" (almost 100 MB in size)

Is it possible to read the file directly from the above mentioned URL and load the data into scala dataframe.

If Yes, would need you help to load the same on my system

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data cannot be directly loaded in to Spark.
You will need to download the file on to disk and then load it in Spark